# How can I stop a program when the user wants to?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I made a program which asks the user the amount of numbers he wants, which numbers he wants and creates a list. I now want to make it so that if the user puts in the number 0 the program will stop there and print the previous numbers he has put if it's possible (note: I want the 0 to not be printed only the previous numbers he entered). Because this is my first time posting I'm not sure what else information is needed other than what version of Python I'm using (which is 2.7). If there's more information that's needed just ask. Also if it's needed I'll write the code I have written down.

```
lst = []
x = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
for i in range(0, x): 
    num = int(input()) 
    lst.append(num)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a if-else statement:

```
if num != 0:  
    lst.append(num)   
else:  
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Before lst.append(num)

```
if num == 0:
    break
```